# Modifying select query

Tags: sql, select

**Existing query:**

```
SELECT av.FIELD3, av.STRINGVALUE FROM attrvalue av 
   WHERE av.FIELD3 IN 
   (
      SELECT ha. EXTNL_ATTR_ID FROM thd.HD_ATTR ha 
        WHERE ha.ATTR_GRP_ID IN (14,15)
   ) 
   AND av.catentry_id >= 100000000
```

Wanted to modify this query to select this column as well:  `ha.ATTR_GRP_ID`.

Please assist.

Comment: i would tag this with SQL, which engine are you using, can you write keywords CAPITAL (readability++) and what have you tried? Is this a homework/assignment (because of the comment after the query "fetch first 10 rows only with ur....")?

Comment: try this: `select av.FIELD3,av.STRINGVALUE,ha.ATTR_GRP_ID from attrvalue av inner join thd.HD_ATTR ha where ha. EXTNL_ATTR_ID=av.FIELD3 and ha.ATTR_GRP_ID in (14,15) and av.catentry_id >= 100000000`

Answer (score 1):

Make a join with the HD_ATTR table

```
SELECT av.FIELD3, av.STRINGVALUE, ha.ATTR_GRP_ID 
FROM attrvalue av 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT _ha.EXTNL_ATTR_ID, _ha.ATTR_GRP_ID 
    FROM thd.HD_ATTR _ha 
    WHERE ha.ATTR_GRP_ID IN (14,15)
) ha
ON ha.EXTNL_ATTR_ID = AV.FIELD3
WHERE av.catentry_id >= 100000000
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the subquery, just add the condition in the `WHERE` clause as part of the join.  But yes, this should be what he's looking for (minus the typographical error in the subquery - you shouldn't need an alias in there anyways).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it this you need to access data from the table in the subquery which cannot be done. Instead you need to restructure this query into a join between the two tables so that you can establish which group goes with which record.

I suggest you attempt this by using an inner join on the two tables